# Is there any difference between the result of these two format strings?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have inherited some code where prices are formatted like this:

```
(1.23d).ToString("£0.00");
```

I would normally format a currency like this:

```
(1.23d).ToString("C");
```

If the machine's locale is set to the UK (which it is) then is there any difference between these two approaches? Can I just do a big find and replace across the solution?

Comment: I wondered whether it would make a difference for negative values, but it doesn't appear to. I hope you're fixing the app to use `decimal` instead of `double` for numeric values, at the same time...

Comment: @JonSkeet It makes a difference in the context of digit grouping.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Ah, right - I didn't try any numbers above 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can partially verify that by running this code on a machine with that locale (or by enforcing it first with `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");`):

```
var nf = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
Console.WriteLine("CurrencyPositivePattern: " + nf.CurrencyPositivePattern);
Console.WriteLine("CurrencyNegativePattern: " + nf.CurrencyNegativePattern);
Console.WriteLine("NegativeSign: " + nf.NegativeSign);
Console.WriteLine("CurrencySymbol: " + nf.CurrencySymbol);
Console.WriteLine("CurrencyDecimalDigits: " + nf.CurrencyDecimalDigits);
Console.WriteLine("CurrencyDecimalSeparator: " + nf.CurrencyDecimalSeparator);
Console.WriteLine("CurrencyGroupSeparator: " + nf.CurrencyGroupSeparator);
Console.WriteLine("CurrencyGroupSizes: " + string.Join(",", nf.CurrencyGroupSizes.Select(gs => gs.ToString())));
```

Note the group sizes property. On my machine this code:

```
Console.WriteLine((1232323d).ToString("C"));
Console.WriteLine((1232323d).ToString("£0.00"));
```

produces two different strings, because of the digit groups.

Also, as noted by others here, and as you may already know anyway - `decimal` should be used instead of `double` for currency.

Answer (score 2):

According to Standard [Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), behavior of the "C" format specifier is determined by settings in the current culture's [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can check to make sure by examining the `NumberFormatInfo`:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
var nfi = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
Console.WriteLine(nfi.CurrencyDecimalDigits);
Console.WriteLine(nfi.CurrencyDecimalSeparator);
Console.WriteLine(nfi.CurrencyNegativePattern);
Console.WriteLine(nfi.CurrencyPositivePattern);
Console.WriteLine(nfi.CurrencySymbol);
```

Comment: You didn't mention currency group sizes which seem crucial here.

Comment: @BartoszKP: An oversight. You can add it.

Answer (score 0):

It will be no difference. If in your Regional language settings desired currency is selected.

And yes, Always prefer `decimal` as data type for money.

Answer (score 0):

`(1.23d).ToString("£0.00");` might make it more explicit that the numbers always represent £ (business logic) and that this is not merely an arbitrary display thing.